# How to derive an editable input value of one field from another in AOR

Tags: admin-on-rest

I've a use case where `Field B` value is derived from `Field A` value, and `Field B` value can be changed by user inputs as well. Is there a way to fire `Field B's` `input.onChange` action when Field A changes? I checked redux-form documentation (and am a bit new to redux-form) and there seem to be action creators at the form level to achieve this. But it looks like a workaround to access the redux-form directly while working on out of box SimpleForm from AOR.

I looked `aor-dependent-input`. But that helps to hide/show input based on another component's value, not to derive value based on another. Thoughts?